# How to use React Router <Link > with an id from antd table column

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, antd

In my project, I have an antd table. In that table, I'm listing athletes. When I click on the athlete's name, I should be navigated to the athlete profile page.

Route for athlete profile `/athletes/{id}`

But with the table, I can't get any value for this `id`.

Here is my data source

```
[
   {
      email: "x@x.com",
      firstName: "X",
      id: 402,
      lastName: "X"
   },
   {
      email: "y@y.com",
      firstName: "Y",
      id: 403,
      lastName: "Y"
   },
   {
      email: "z@z.com",
      firstName: "Z",
      id: 404,
      lastName: "Z"
   }
]
```

And following is the code for the column object

```
const columns = [
      {
        title: "First Name",
        dataIndex: "firstName",
        className: "col-first-name",
        render: (text) => (
          <Link to={"/athletes/" + ???}>{text}</Link>
        ),
      },
      {
        title: "Last Name",
        dataIndex: "lastName",
        className: "col-last-name"
      },
      {
        title: "Email",
        dataIndex: "email",
        className: "col-email",
      }
    ];
```

(I have added "???" where the `id` should be, in the above code)
Is there any way to add the `id` property into the ? Can anyone help me with this?

react-router version - "^5.1.2"
antd version - ^3.25.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass another `parameter`  inside render which is `record` which contains all data about that specific row. Something like this:

```
const columns = [
      {
        title: "First Name",
        dataIndex: "firstName",
        className: "col-first-name",
        render: (text,record) => (
          <Link to={"/athletes/" + record.id}>{text}</Link>
        ),
      },
      {
        title: "Last Name",
        dataIndex: "lastName",
        className: "col-last-name"
      },
      {
        title: "Email",
        dataIndex: "email",
        className: "col-email",
      }
    ];
```

I created this demo for reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ym57ax?file=index.js

Answer (score 1):

The render function receive three parameters: first one is retrieved using the dataIndex, second one is the complete record and last one is the index.

You can use:

```
const columns = [{
    title: "First Name",
    dataIndex: "firstName",
    className: "col-first-name",
    render: (text, record) => (
        <Link to={`/athletes/${record.id}`}>{text}</Link>
    ),
}, {
    title: "Last Name",
    dataIndex: "lastName",
    className: "col-last-name"
}, {
    title: "Email",
    dataIndex: "email",
    className: "col-email",
}];
```